# Ebean select function always taking id column only

Tags: java, sql, playframework, ebean

In Ebean select(String properties) function always taking id of the table. I know select function take id default but in my case although i am giving different properties(column name) it is taking only id

This the query running in log

```
txn[1001] select t0.id c0, t0.id c1 from commission_rates t0; --bind()
```

play version - 2.5.9

this is the entity for that:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "commission_rates")
public class CommissionRates extends Model {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    @Column(name = "commission_type", nullable = false)
    private CommissionType commissionType;

    @Column(name = "commission_value", nullable = false)
    private float commissionValue;

    @Column(name = "applicable")
    private int applicable;

    @Column(name = "from_date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date fromDate;

    @CreatedTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created_time", columnDefinition = "datetime", updatable = false)
    private Date createdTime;
}
```

Ebean query:

```
CommissionRates a = Ebean.find(CommissionRates.class).select("commission_type").findUnique();
```

I want to select a commission_type column along with id. Find a way to get me out.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of doing DB query using ebean `Model.Finder` use the Model class filed names and in case of Ebean.find(ModelClass.class) use DB column name.

> Note: this not only applies to select, but all

if you want to use your Model class fild name instead of db coulmn name add

```
public static final Finder<Long, ClassName> find = new Finder<>(ClassName.class);
```

and you can do `ClassName.find.select("commissionType").findUnique();`

in case you want to fetch more than one field use **,** as separator in select method.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution Found:**

In select function we need pass the variable name of the Entity not the column name 
Eg :

```
CommissionRates a = Ebean.find(CommissionRates.class).select("commissionType").findUnique();
```

not as:

```
CommissionRates a = Ebean.find(CommissionRates.class).select("commission_type").findUnique();
```